# Symphonyoss - retrieve the list of users I chat with

Tags: java, maven

Is it possible to retrieve the list of users I chat with using symphonyoss dependency ?

Please refer below dependency which i am using ,

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.symphonyoss.symphony</groupId>
        <artifactId>symphony-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

I want to create a panel right of my page where I will display the list of all cats of the connected user, and when he clicks on a chat, a popup opens with the history of the discussion

i have found chat service, but got null at result with all our symphony users !

```
  @Autowired
  org.symphonyoss.client.SymphonyClient symphonyClient;
  // ....

  SymUser remoteUser = symphonyClient.getUsersClient().getUserFromEmail("Takfa.Imehrazen@afnay.com");

  Set<Chat> listChats = symphonyClient.getChatService().getChats(remoteUser);
  // listChats is all times null

  Set<SymUser> listuser = symphonyClient.getUsersClient().getUsersFromStream(remoteUser.getId().toString());
   // listuser is null too
```

Comment: How or what is `remoteUser`?

Comment: thank you for your response, i have edited the post, i add the remte client declaration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This get the list on one to one stream,

```
  List<SymStreamAttributes> listuser3 = symphonyClient.getStreamsClient().getStreams((Integer) 1, (Integer) 10, new SymStreamFilter());

  for (SymStreamAttributes symStream : listuser3) {
        sm = new Stream();
        List<Long> listmembers = (symStream.getSymChatSpecificStreamAttributes() != null) ? symStream.getSymChatSpecificStreamAttributes().getMembers() : null;
        for (Long userId : listmembers) {
            if (userId != localUser.getUserId()) {
                SymUser contact = symphonyClient.getUsersClient().getUserFromId(userId);
                sm.setDisplayName(contact.getDisplayName());
                sm.setId(contact.getId());
                listSendedUser.add(sm);
            }
        }

    }
    return listSendedUser;
```

If you want get also room stream use

```
  symStream.getSymRoomSpecificStreamAttributes()
```